# Default bullet style in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2010

My company just came out with some branding and I've been tasked with developing the new Microsoft Word (2007+) template.

The marketing consultant insisted that the first level bullets must be 12pt and the second level bullets must be 10pt.

How can I set this up in the template?

Comment: You mean the size of the bullet points themselves or the size of the text that's indented?

Comment: @slhck I'm not 100% sure, but I think he means the size of the bullets themselves.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but I am mostly concerned with the text. If the size of the bullet changes with the text that is fine, but what I really need to do is have level one bullet text to be 12pt and level two bullet text to be 10pt.

Comment: Pretty much everything has a corresponding paragraph style that is used to determine fonts, colors, size etc. Customize the paragraph style for each element the marketing consultant wants. For example the paragraph styles "List Bullet", "List Bullet 2".

Answer (score 1):

On Home tab, expand Styles, select one of the items in the list as a starting point (say List Paragraph) and click on New Style (bottom left).

Change Name to something meaningful (say Bullet 12p) and under Formatting enter or select 12 immediately to the right of the font name, OK.

Select Bullet 12p instead of List Paragraph, click on New Style and change Name (say to Bullet 10p). Under formatting enter or select 10 immediately to the right of the font name, OK.

In the Styles part of the Home tab you should now be able to see Bullet 10p and Bullet 12p. If the latter is clicked after selecting the first three lines of text in the example below and the former after selecting the last three lines as below, the results should be of the following nature:

[image: SU346697 example]

But numerous other elements are controllable, particularly via the <kbd>Format</kbd> button on the Create New Style from Formatting window, so "YMMV"!